# how to delete unusable data in python?

Tags: python, dataset, accelerometer

I have a set of data of accelerometer. This data is related to going forward then stop and turn and come back. I don't want the data of stopping and turning, and I want to delete this data from my data set. would you please let me know how to do this in python?[the figure of this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmsMx.jpg)

Comment: Show us what you tried, show us the data, etc. Give us something to work with.

Comment: Imagine someone asked this question of you. Do you feel you would have enough information about their data, what platform they were using, what database it was stored in, etc to give them any reasonable answer?

Comment: ok i added the figure of my data. i hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really see your code, so my answer is pretty limited. I am assuming that you want to know how to delete a range of elements in a list (please correct me if I am wrong). In the code below, you have to give the value of the index range that you have to delete.

```
dataset = [10, 20, 50, 15, 50, 50, 901, 1000, 800]   #whatever your dataset is
startpop = 3  #the starting index of the data to be erased
endpop = 7    #the ending index of the data to be erased

del dataset[startpop:endpop]
```